# GUI anthentication doesn't work. No privileges

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, sudo, privileges, policykit

This is on Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit

After a forced restart (due to nvidia overheating) I noticed that no sound was playing, and in fact pulseaudio showed only dummy devices. While looking for a solution, I even reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa-base completely, without success.

I noticed then that something else is also wrong - some notification area icons are missing too... and then that also any program that would normally ask for a sudo password, now either doesnt do anything or tells me I don't have privileges.

"Software & Updates" yelded once an error with detailed message like:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.136'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache
```

So it seems like something about polkit? This might be due to some random update that happened before the forced restart, or it might not. I don't really know.

I can do sudo from the console, I am in sudo group also.

I tried `sudo pam-auth-update --force` without success, and also reinstalled policykit-1 and policykit-1-gnome.

Any ideas what's wrong?